# android preference screen inconvertible types

Tags: android

I am trying to create a preferenceScreen with this command

```
        PreferenceScreen screen= (PreferenceScreen)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(KEY);
```

and the error message is: "inconvertible types, cannot cast android.support.v7.preference.Preference to android.preference.preferenceScreen"

Is there a way to fix it? Thanks!

Update: this is part of the testing code I wrote

```
        ArrayList<String> cmds = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("A");
        add("B");
        add("C");
    }};
    for (String cmd : cmds) {
    CheckBoxPreference cpref = new CheckBoxPreference(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        cpref.setTitle(cmd);
        cpref.setKey("The Name");
        cpref.setChecked(true);
        cmdScr.addPreference(cpref);
    }
```

now the last line "addPreference" gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findPreference` returns `android.support.v7.preference.Preference` and not the `PreferenceScreen`. What you need to do is this:

```
Preference screen = (Preference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference(KEY);
```

Where `Preference` is imported as the one from the support library:

```
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
```

To answer your edited question, just visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129384/programatically-populating-preferences-with-checkboxes) to see what you're doing wrong. Add the category to your screen, and then add the preference to the category.

Comment: hi @Vucko thanks for your reply. How do I import preference as the one from the support library so that the "screen" I got is a preferenceScreen?

Comment: If you're extending `PreferenceActivity` you can use `getPreferenceManager()` instead of `getPreferenceScreen()`

Comment: I am extending PreferenceFragmentCompat ,could you write an example please? I am kind of new to android. Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem now dude? Is it not working? I wrote you exactly what you need. `PreferenceFragmentCompat ` has the method `getPreferenceManager()`. Use it to find the preference with the key.

Comment: Hi Vucko I was trying to call the addPreference(screen) method after using the code you wrote.

Comment: Did you make it work? I presume that by accepting the answer, you did?

Comment: @Xia Edited my answer with a link that'll help you.