# Programmatically create Preference that opens a webpage?

Tags: java, android

I already have a preference screen that uses preferences from xml but I would like to create a Preference that opens a webpage url using an intent. However, the url comes from another preference.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to programmatically create this preference so I can inject this url on creation of the preference screen.

What I've tried so far is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129384/programmatically-populating-preferences-with-checkboxes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but that's only for a checkbox preference. I wanted to make a preference that would normally have an intent with `android:action` and `android:data` in its xml. For example:

```
<Preference android:title="@string/prefs_web_page">
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:data="http://192.168.1.104" />
</Preference>
```

How can I do this programmatically? Thank you!