# How do I set MultiSelectListPreference's checkbox values programatically?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'am working on an android application, which gets summary of a preference from shared Preferences and now I have to set these values to this dialog 
box of the MultiSelectListPreference.

I am getting something like this (the summary is correct but the dialog values are not checked)

[image]

The code I used to bind the summary with value change(working fine):

```
        objects.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                String values;
                objects.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                values = newValue.toString().replace("[", "");
                values = values.replace("]", "");
                editorObjects.putString(UserSharedPref.objectList, values);

                editorObjects.commit();
                return true;
             }
         });
```

The values and summary is binded in the above example.

I'am initializing values from user shared prefs like this (working fine):

> objects.setSummary(["+UserSharedPref.initializeSharedPreferencesForObjectList(getApplicationContext()).getString(UserSharedPref.objectList,
>   "person,bicycle,motorcycle,car,bus,truck") + "]");

But, to check the values based on this summary is where I'am getting the problem.
How should  my approach be?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6129451/7649582

Comment: Can you post some code so that we get some idea?

Comment: hey @AlokGupta, just edited this question..Check it out...:)

Comment: Hey, @Dhanshri, not working...like CheckBoxPreference can't be used in place of MultiSelectListPreference...some cast error are encountered.